# changes in vertices and edges on undirected graph

Tags: c++, boost, graph-theory

Im using visual studio c++, boost.

Lets say I have undirected graph. every t seconds I need to check if it changed (vertices\edges removed\added).

The time complexity is quite important.

This is an example of building the graph:

```
typedef adjacency_matrix<undirectedS> UGraph;
    UGraph G(9);
    add_edge(1, 2, G);
    add_edge(2, 5, G);
    add_edge(5, 1, G);
    add_edge(3, 6, G);
    add_edge(3, 4, G);
    add_edge(7, 8, G);
```

since I use `adjacency_matrix`, the time complexity of `add_edge()`, `remove_edge()`, `add_vertex()` and `remove_vertex()` is O(1).

I thought of using `add_edge()` to check if that edge is already exist, by its return value:

```
retVal = add_edge(1, 2, G);
if(already exist)
 //do something
else
 //do something else

retVal = add_vertex(1,G);
if(already exist)
 //do something
else
 //do something else
```

but from my understanding, if I add edge to existing one (in undirected graph), it will be added in parallel to to the existing edge.

so, is there a fat way (my way or other way), to check changes (both vertices and edges) between two undirected graphs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

o.k

after doing some reading, this is what I found:

Checking if edge exist-

```
graph_traits<UGraph>::edge_descriptor e;   //UGraph is the undirected graph
bool found = false;

boost::tie(e, found) = edge(1, 2, G); //found = true
boost::tie(e, found) = edge(1, 3, G); //found = false
boost::tie(e, found) = edge(2, 1, G); //found = true
```

the other way:

```
found = edge(1, 2, G).second; //found = true
found = edge(1, 3, G).second; //found = false
```

Checking if vertex exist-

I didn't find any built in function, but specific vertex could be found on `adjacency_matrix`